# combining links into one one output in beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab all of the links with a certain div tag which I can accomplish.  The problem is every link is displayed in a new line.  For example:

```
Home

Wire Wheels
Crimped
```

I would like it to show Home,Wire Wheels,Crimped

Is this possible?

Here is the python code I am using to grab the data:

```
for crumbs in soup.find('div',{"id":"breadcrumbs"}).find_all('a'):
        crumbs2 = crumbs.text
        print(crumbs2)
```

Comment: Is `soup.find('div',{"id":"breadcrumbs"}).find_all('a')` a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a different line-ending to print. The default is `os.linesep`:

```
crumbs = list(soup.find('div',{"id":"breadcrumbs"}).find_all('a'))
for ind, crumb in enumerate(crumbs):
    if ind < len(crumbs) - 1:
        ending = {'end': ', '}
    else:
        ending = {}
    print(crumb.text, **ending)
```

That being said, you should definitely go with @alecxe's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to get the stripped text directly and [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join the strings:

```
",".join([crumbs.get_text(strip=True) 
          for crumbs in soup.find('div',{"id":"breadcrumbs"}).find_all('a')])
```

Also note that `soup.find('div',{"id":"breadcrumbs"}).find_all('a')` can be simplified to `soup.select("#breadcrumbs a")`.

Comment: Sorry I am new but is this what you mean:  for crumbs in soup.join([crumbs.get_text(strip=True)
    for crumbs in soup.find('div',{"id":"breadcrumbs"}).find_all('a')]

Comment: @PatrickP76 no, I mean exactly what is posted in the answer, join with a comma - as you've asked about.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work for me and I have tried a number of different ways